# Finding number of occurences of all characters in three strings in C++

Tags: c++

I don't understand why this program is not working.

I need to find the number of occurrences of all characters in three strings by any method.

I used count method but if you guys can help me out with find function so it would be better.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line[3];
    int count[3];
    cout << "Enter three lines of text...\n\n";
    cin >> line[0];
    cin >> line[1];
    cin >> line[2];
    int i;
    for(char j='a'; j<=26; j++) {
        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            count[i] = std::count(line[i].begin(), line[i].end(), j);
        cout << "\n" << j << "\t" << ":" << "\t" << count[i];
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you formatted your code properly then at least one of several bugs would become immediately apparent.

Comment: @user1885560 i didn't understand can you show a output format that you want?

Comment: i need output in a way that each character's number of occurences should come separately...

Comment: like this...
a: number
b: number...
and so on...

Answer (score 3):

26 is no letter, and `(char)26` is normally less than `'a'` - so your loop will not execute. Try `char j='a';j<='z';j++`

Answer (score 3):

I would go for something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Given 3 strings...
    std::string s1 = "Hello";
    std::string s2 = "Cruel";
    std::string s3 = "World";

    //===============================================
    // THESE 2 LINES ARE ALL YOU NEED FOR COUNTING
    std::map<char, int> countMap;
    for (char c : (s1 + s2 + s3)) { countMap[c]++; }
    //===============================================

    // Print the output. This is if you do not care about
    // characters that do not appear at all.
    for (auto const& e : countMap)
    {
        std::cout << e.first << ": " << e.second << std::endl;
    }

    // Print the output. This is if you DO care about
    // characters that do not appear at all.
    for (char c = ' '; c <= '~'; c++)
    {
        std::cout << c << ": " << countMap[c] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.asciitable.com/

Lower case 'a' is 96. Which is less than 26 which is why your loop doesn't execute. Try:

```
for (char j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j++)
```

This will only count the lower case characters. If you wanted the occurrence of lower and upper case you could do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line[3];

    cout << "Enter three lines of text...\n\n";
    cin >> line[0];
    cin >> line[1];
    cin >> line[2];

    for(char j='a';j<='z';j++)
    {
        int upper_sum = 0;
        int lower_sum = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            lower_sum += std::count(line[i].begin(),line[i].end(),j);
            upper_sum += std::count(line[i].begin(),line[i].end(),j - 32); //32 = 'a' - 'A'
        }

        cout<<"\n"<<j<<"\t"<<":"<<"\t"<<lower_sum;
        cout<<"\n"<<(char)(j - 32)<<"\t"<<":"<<"\t"<<upper_sum;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but in this way i wont get all the counts of three lines...it will give the output of only the third line... because at the cout statement the value of i is 3... i need count[0]+count[1]+count[2]... how will i get this..?

Comment: Edited for the i = 3 thing. Ok so you want the combined count of a letter from all the strings?

Comment: yes yes... exactly... now u got what i am trying to calculate... number of each letter in all three strings.. combinely..

Comment: thanks... let me try this to0... i will tell u after an hour about whether it worked or not...

Comment: this to0 is not working... its giving output like.. 1940080 this much value at each character...

Comment: no its not working... now i have updated upper sum and lower sum=0 after printing them in the outer for loop... now its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a correct version of your program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string line[3];
int count[3];
/*cout<<"Enter three lines of text...\n\n";
cin>>line[0];
cin>>line[1];
cin>>line[2];*/

      line[0] = "aaaaabbbbbbbbbbb";
      line[1] = "ccccccddddddddddd";
      line[2] = "kkkkkkkkkkkkk";

     int i;
     for(char j='a';j<= 'z';j++) // You can loop through the alphabet, but you need to go 'a' to 'z' and not 26
     { 

             for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
             { // You were missing these braces,  you need them if your loop contains multiple lines
               count[i]= std::count(line[i].begin(),line[i].end(),j);
               cout<<"\n"<<j<<"\t"<<":"<<"\t"<<count[i];
             }
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

And here [it is](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1aOQ6F%247) in action.

Comment: i dont need the braces for the loop... why everyone is putting braces when i dont want the cout line to be included in the loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
for(char j='a'; j<=26; j++) {
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        count[i] = std::count(line[i].begin(), line[i].end(), j);
    cout << "\n" << j << "\t" << ":" << "\t" << count[i];
}
```

Your `cout` line isn't in the inner `for` loop.

After the inner loop finishes, `i` is `3`. Then `cout` is called with `count[i]` which goes out of bounds on the array. Undefined behaviour, you're lucky if it crashes.

Your problem is the `i`. The place it's declared means it still exists and the `cout` line can reference it. If you move the declaration to the loop initialiser you'll find the next error:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    count[i] = std::count(line[i].begin(), line[i].end(), j);
cout << "\n" << j << "\t" << ":" << "\t" << count[i];
```

The last line won't compile as `i` goes out of scope at the end of the loop. I assume you were mistaken in thinking `cout` was part of the loop, partly due to the poor formatting of the code, and secondly because `i` was declared at a wider scope.

To correct this, create a block for the `for` loop by using `{` and `}`. This will keep the `i` in scope for all statements within the block, and repeat the statements for each iteration of the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    count[i] = std::count(line[i].begin(), line[i].end(), j);
    cout << "\n" << j << "\t" << ":" << "\t" << count[i];
}
```

Comment: the cout line below the for loop is outside the loop... i never wanted to make it a part of the loop.. its not poor programming at least i know it... i did not put brackets because i wanted it to remain outside the loop... well i am done with the program i got it done with re initialising count[] to zero...

Comment: The `cout` doesn't make sense there though because it's outputting `count[3]`, which is undefined. The valid values are `count[0]`, `count[1]`, and `count[2]`.